# mod_rewrite: dynamic redirect and directory blocking

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am working on an .htaccess-file lying in mysite.com/dir/.htaccess that redirects mysite.com/dir/page to mysite.com/dir/page.php if possible and redirect to mysite.com/dir/ if not possible. So any "wrong" request will be redirected to the main page. The code im using is:

```
RewriteEngine on

# determine DIR_BASE dynamically
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=DIR_BASE:%1]

# see if .php is found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# if not found redirect to %{ENV:DIR_BASE}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:DIR_BASE} [R]
```

This all works well. (By the way: i want to determine the base-dir of the file, because i maybe want to change the directory name later, but not change the file). What i now want is to block some directories for the user, because they contain php-libraries that should not be accessible. how can i e.g. block the directories mysite.com/dir/lib/* and mysite.com/dir/lib2/* and redirect them to mysite.com/dir/ again like i did before? I also want to use code not like

```
RewriteRule ^lib/(.)* %{ENV:DIR_BASE}
```

that would redirect mysite.com/dir/lib/../page to the main page instead of mysite.com/dir/page where it should belong. i tried very much with %{REQUEST_FILENAME} and %{REQUEST_URI}, but i am only a beginner when it comes to mod_rewrite. do you know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

# determine DIR_BASE dynamically
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=DIR_BASE:%1]

RewriteRule ^lib2?(/|$) %{ENV:DIR_BASE} [L,NC,R]

# see if .php is found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# if not found redirect to %{ENV:DIR_BASE}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:DIR_BASE} [L,R]
```

Comment: yes, it does work well, thank you very much. isnt this also the second time you answered a question for me?